# react development server not starting, but errors logged in my terminal

Tags: reactjs

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "set PORT=3006 && react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider start",
```

this is what it looks like in my packages.json, but when running `npm start` at my app directory, says starting development server but the tab still loads for like an hour

i havent tried anything, should I reinstall npm install?